# Python requests and Ad.fly

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a question and I'm going to take Ad.fly as an example.

I guess that it is possible for example to visit an Ad.fly link with `requests` and basically "click" on "Skip Ad" in Python.

But how can I theoretically do that ?

I don't need an answer with a Python code, I just want to understand what exactly happens when I visit a website and click on a button that don't need to retrieve any input from the website.

Web isn't my field at all, but don't hesitate to give me a complete answer even if it's complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Requests library would not achieve this on its own; it's just an HTTP client library. You need something that can interact with the web page.

Either a web driver like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/projects/) (which uses browser command bindings to simulate a user), or a combination of Requests (for sending the HTTP request), [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (for parsing the HTML) and [MechanicalSoup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (for interacting with the web page) would do the trick.

Alternatively, if you really wanted to just use the Requests library, you could determine the URL schema of the anchor element for the "Skip Ad" button and send a `GET` request directly to that URL, which would theoretically, if it doesn't use session values or other tracking, send you directly to the following content.